# Cosa significa "passare la parte" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> – Beh, ragazze, – dissi io cercando anche un mezzo sbadiglio. – Arrivederci a Loreto o ad Oropa o magari anche in tutti e due i posti. Mettete insieme una bella cosetta, capite? Ma il fatto è che adesso purtroppo ho un bel mucchio di cose da fare: e cosí, se non vi dispiace, me ne torno a tirar la carretta. 
>          Era un **passare la parte**, lo so: ma cosí le due oneste galline se ne andarono via sgambettando.

Queste "due oneste galline" sono due "Figlie di Maria" che vogliono organizzare un "pellegrinaggio ad Oropa o a Loreto o magari anche in tutti e due i posti".

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "passare la parte" in questo brano. Ho cercato alla voce "parte" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente al riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 1):

Il significato è quello di "passare la mano" ossia di rinunciare ad un'impresa, ritirarsi.

Answer (score 0):

"Parte" nel senso di "ruolo": il personaggio sta dismettendo il "ruolo" di accompagnatore delle due donne.